# How can I send an array that's generated with Python code, over to my Android App?

Tags: android, python

I'm trying to run a python script on my webserver and it returns some arrays. I need to deliver them to my Android App. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Setup a REST endpoint on the server, serialize the arrays to JSON to be retrieved with a GET call in the Android app.

Comment: Currently, I've been trying to setup a database on the server and upload to there with Python and get them with Android. I've never used those APIs you mentioned  before. You think they are better? @Noah

Comment: It depends on the usage. I do think the REST solution would be easier, however if the dataset is changing all the time, then that may not be the optimal solution.